# NodeJS + MySQL - Коверкает число

Tags: mysql, node.js

В базе данных есть некий SteamID:

> 76561198160247832

Он лежит в ячейке (steamid) в базе данных.
Я случайным образом выбираю одну строку с каким-либо steamid (в данном случае строка содержит предоставленный выше стимайди), и вывожу его в консоль:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE id=" + mysql.escape(id), function (err, result20, fields) {
log("Победитель: " + result20[0].steamid);
```

Мне возвращает:

> Победитель: 76561198160247840

В чём может быть проблема?
В таблице steamid имеет тип bigint (255) и заполнен верно.

Comment: Передавайте строкой, а не числом. Точности обычного числа не хватает и оно "коверкает" цифры не влезшие в точность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как говорилось в ответе выше - для записи таких длинных чисел тупо "не хватает памяти",
но это можно исправить двумя строками:

При `CreateConnection` указать параметры:

```
supportBigNumbers: true, bigNumberStrings: true.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Из 64 бит, отведённых на число, сами цифры числа занимают до 52 бит, остальные 11 бит хранят позицию десятичной точки и один бит – знак. Так что если 52 бит не хватает на цифры, то при записи пропадут младшие разряды.
>
> Интерпретатор не выдаст ошибку, но в результате получится «не совсем то число», что мы и видим в примере выше. Как говорится: «как смог, так записал».

[источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/number)

Проще говоря, если в числе больше 16 знаков, будет искажение:

```js
console.log(76561198160247832)
console.log(765611981602478328)
```

Comment: Я с помощью гугла нашел ответ на мой вопрос. Это действительно так.